# Why doesn't Amplify.configure() work with a .env file?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, aws-amplify, .env

I am building a NextJS web app that uses AWS Amplify for authentication, and I have the following:

`_app.tsx`:

```
import awsExports from "../../aws-exports";
...
Amplify.configure({
  Auth: {
    region: awsExports.REGION,
    userPoolId: awsExports.USER_POOL_ID,
    userPoolWebClientId: awsExports.USER_POOL_APP_CLIENT_ID,
  },
});
...
```

`aws-exports.js`:

```js
export default {
  REGION: "xxxxxxx",
  USER_POOL_ID: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  USER_POOL_APP_CLIENT_ID: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
};
```

When I do it that way, everything works great. However, I wanted to add the configuration into my `.env.local` file, so I changed `aws-exports.js` as follows:

```js
export default {
  REGION: process.env.AMPLIFY_REGION,
  USER_POOL_ID: process.env.AMPLIFY_USER_POOL_ID,
  USER_POOL_APP_CLIENT_ID: process.env.AMPLIFY_USER_POOL_APP_CLIENT_ID,
};
```

and added the following lines to `.env.local`

```
AMPLIFY_REGION=xxxxxxx
AMPLIFY_USER_POOL_ID=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
AMPLIFY_USER_POOL_APP_CLIENT_ID=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

But as soon as I made that change, I started getting an error in the console:

```
client.js?4d30:1 [ERROR] 54:28.346 AuthError - 
            Error: Amplify has not been configured correctly. 
            The configuration object is missing required auth properties.
            This error is typically caused by one of the following scenarios:

            1. Did you run `amplify push` after adding auth via `amplify add auth`?
                See https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/js/authentication#amplify-project-setup for more information

            2. This could also be caused by multiple conflicting versions of amplify packages, see (https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/troubleshooting/upgrading/q/platform/js) for help upgrading Amplify packages.
```

and if I print out the config, I see that all three fields are undefined.
Is it the case that .env files can only be accessed in backend code? If so, how should I go about configuring Amplify? I suppose the browser needs this configuration one way or another, so should it just be left in the source code like I had it originally?

Thanks in advance for any advice

Comment: What build tool are you using? Webpack or Vite maybe? If you're using the latter you need to update your build/run command to add `--mode local` so it knows to use your .env.local config

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR: add `NEXT_PUBLIC_` before the environment variables with values you want to use in your front end code

NextJs tries to protect you from exporting potentially sensitive environment variables to the public.  Thus, it blocks the inclusion of data from process.env (where the variables in `.env.local` are loaded into) from being shared in your front end code.

You can bypass that behavior by prefixing your variable names with `NEXT_PUBLIC_`.  For details, [see the environment variables docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/configuring/environment-variables#bundling-environment-variables-for-the-browser).  Note that [destructuring and other means of accessing the variables will be ignored](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/a63c74924af91fe0afe510fea04f77f1da7f923c/packages/next/src/build/webpack/plugins/define-env-plugin.ts#L61).  The variable must be accessed with the equivalent of `process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_${VAR_NAME}`.

For you, the following should work:

`aws-exports.js`

```
export default {
  REGION: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_AMPLIFY_REGION,
  USER_POOL_ID: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_AMPLIFY_USER_POOL_ID,
  USER_POOL_APP_CLIENT_ID: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_AMPLIFY_USER_POOL_APP_CLIENT_ID,
};
```

`.env.local`

```
NEXT_PUBLIC_AMPLIFY_REGION=xxxxxxx
NEXT_PUBLIC_AMPLIFY_USER_POOL_ID=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
NEXT_PUBLIC_AMPLIFY_USER_POOL_APP_CLIENT_ID=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```